# grouped bar plot for survey categorical data

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e77DQ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUlgG.png)

```
   Q1[data$Q11 == -99] <- NA

Q1s<- factor(Q1 , labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"))
levels(SQ1s )# how many levels of a categorical variable
Q11frequency <- table (Q1s ) #frequency
Q11frequency
#percentages
Q1_PERCENTAGE=prop.table(table(Q1s)) * 100
Q1_PERCENTAGE

barplot(Q1_PERCENTAGE)


Q2[data$Q2 == -99] <- NA

Q2s<- factor(Q2s , labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"))
levels(Q2s )# how many levels of a categorical variable
Q2sfrequency <- table (Q2s ) #frequency
Q2sfrequency
#percentages
Q2s_PERCENTAGE=prop.table(table(Q2s)) * 100
Q2s_PERCENTAGE

barplot(Q2s_PERCENTAGE)
```

I get individual graphs such as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Uh2.png)

But I am looking for a group bar plot for the data. any help?

Comment: Hi @James and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think that your question is fine, but it lacks details (what are the groups by which bars should be grouped?). You also showed what you tried (`barplot`). Your chances of getting an answer will increase if you 1) make some example data available, e.g. using `dput` (please never use images to show raw data), and 2) make a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with just the code needed to understand your question.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this might help you

```
#Libraries

library(tidyverse)

#Example Data
qlevels <- c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")
         
df <- 
  tibble(
    Q1 = runif(n = 100,1,5),
    Q2 = runif(n = 100,1,5),
    Q3 = runif(n = 100,1,5),
    Q4 = runif(n = 100,1,5)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(.fns = round),
    across(.fns = function(x)factor(x,labels = qlevels))
    )

#How to

df %>% 
  #Pivot data to create a single column for all Q values
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  #Count for each Question and level
  count(name,value) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(p = 100*n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name,y = p))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = value), col = "black")+
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "div")
```

[image]